# Laravel Livewire: Possible to use AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-livewire

The programming language we've used is: Laravel Livewire.

In the application there's 2 users: 1) Member; 2) Admin.

We have module called "Activities" where the admin can only create,read,update and inactive/active  while the Member has a dashboard where they can see all active activities.

I implemented the fullCalendar, I managed to fetch and display the data. Now what I want is when the activity is clicked, it will show the activity details will using modal.

**Controller**

```
public function getActivityDetails(Request $request)
    {
        $data                                       = $request->all();
        $activity                                   = Activity::where('id',$data['id']);
        dd($activity);

        return response()->json($activity);
    }
```

**View**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers:{
               'X-CSRF-TOKEN' : $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });


        var activities = @json($activities);
        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header:{
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek, agendaDay'
            },
            events: activities,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            selectable: true,
            eventClick: function(event) {
                if (event.id) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/members-dashboard/getActivityDetails",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {
                            id: event.id
                        },
                        success:function(data){
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    })
                }
            }
            // select: function(start, end, allDays){
            //     var value = $(this).val();
            //     console.log(value);
            //     $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
            // }

        });

        function successResponse(data)
        {
            calendar.fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
        }
    });

</script>
```

**WEB**

```
use App\Http\Livewire\MembersPortal\MembersDashboard\ActivityDetails;
Route::post('/members-dashboard/getActivityDetails',MembersDashboard::class,'getActivityDetails')->middleware((['auth']));
```

NOTE: When I tried to console.log the data, it gives me all the html

Question: How can I return the value in my controller?

Comment: This is not a Livewire design, is more a classical Laravel MCV with Jquery at the frontend.

Comment: Using JQuery and AJAX in Livewire completely defeats the purpose of Livewire, so I would reconsider.

Anyway, you should use an array for your JSON response:

`return response()->json(['activity' => $activity]);`

Answer (score 0):

I think that you could use Two components

Activities an ActivitiyDetails components.

The first component will fetch all activities and eager loads activity details at the mount method.

```
$public Activity $activities;

public function mount(){

 $this->activities= Activity::with('details')->where(...);
}
```

After that in your view you will have all your activities and the related activitities detail avoiding to use JQuery to fetch detail for each activity.

The second component could be ActivityDetail, which will accept a param of type ActivityDetail object.

In your view

```
<div>
     @foreach ($activities as $activity)
       <livewire:activity-detail :post="$activity->details">
     @endforeach
</div>
```

I hope this help.